# Show Query output / Number of Total Records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have below query

```
select Count(*), FUNCTIONAL_CLASS from RDF_NAV_LINK where 
(LINK_ID NOT IN (Select DEST_LINK_ID from RDF_SIGN_DESTINATION) AND
LINK_ID NOT IN (Select ORIGINATING_LINK_ID from RDF_SIGN_ORIGIN))
GROUP BY FUNCTIONAL_CLASS
```

I like to show the Query output Like below

```
Count(*) FUNCTIONAL_CLASS
152/252   1
2563/2655 2
251/5485  3
451/562   4
542/562   5
```

Here 152 is number of records which satisfy where condition 
and 252 is number of total records which satisfy FUNCTIONAL_CLASS = 1

is it possible ?

Comment: Don't use tags that do not apply to your question. What database system are you actually using?

Comment: Ok... I am using SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the WHERE clause, you have thrown away all information about the ignored rows.

To get the total count of rows, you have to count them separately:

```
SELECT count(*) || '/' || (SELECT count(*)
                           FROM RDF_NAV_LINK AS link2
                           WHERE link2.FUNCTIONAL_CLASS = link.FUNCTIONAL_CLASS),
       FUNCTIONAL_CLASS
FROM RDF_NAV_LINK AS link
WHERE LINK_ID NOT IN (SELECT DEST_LINK_ID        FROM RDF_SIGN_DESTINATION)
  AND LINK_ID NOT IN (SELECT ORIGINATING_LINK_ID FROM RDF_SIGN_ORIGIN)
GROUP BY FUNCTIONAL_CLASS
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using LEFT JOINs to determine the LINK_IDs that are missing in the ORIGIN and DESTINATION tables, as below:

```
SELECT
    fn_class_groups.FUNCTIONAL_CLASS,
    CONCAT(fn_class_groups.not_in_cnt,'/',fn_class_groups.total_cnt)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        FUNCTIONAL_CLASS,
        COUNT(rnl.LINK_ID) total_cnt,
        SUM
        (CASE
            WHEN rsd.DEST_LINK_ID IS NULL AND rso.ORIGINATING_LINK_ID IS NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) not_in_cnt
    FROM RDF_NAV_LINK rnl
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DEST_LINK_ID FROM RDF_SIGN_DESTINATION) rsd ON rnl.LINK_ID = rsd.DEST_LINK_ID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ORIGINATING_LINK_ID FROM RDF_SIGN_ORIGIN) rso ON rnl.LINK_ID = rso.ORIGINATING_LINK_ID
    GROUP BY FUNCTIONAL_CLASS
    ) fn_class_groups
ORDER BY fn_class_groups.FUNCTIONAL_CLASS;
```

Answer (score 0):

you either need to use 2 queries or one with a subquery:

```
select CONCAT((
    select Count(*) from RDF_NAV_LINK where 
   (LINK_ID NOT IN (Select DEST_LINK_ID from RDF_SIGN_DESTINATION) AND
   LINK_ID NOT IN (Select ORIGINATING_LINK_ID from RDF_SIGN_ORIGIN))
   AND FUNCTIONAL_CLASS = parentTable.FUNCTIONAL_CLASS 
   GROUP BY FUNCTIONAL_CLASS`)
   ,"/",Count(*)), FUNCTIONAL_CLASS from RDF_NAV_LINK as parentTable
GROUP BY FUNCTIONAL_CLASS`
```